# Set the SiteUrlLogo using JSOM in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, custom-masterpage, jsom, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way we can set the SiteUrlLogo using JSOM in custom Master Page using visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is also made available for SP2013 on-prem but in O365 it should be possible as this was added to the API some time ago: https://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/uservoice-driving-improvements-sharepoint-api/.

Have a look here for an example: http://mosshowto.blogspot.nl/2015/10/branding-sharepoint-online-javascript.html.

Snippet from the link:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();

web.set_masterUrl('/sites/intranet2/_catalogs/masterpage/oslo.master');
web.set_siteLogoUrl('/sites/intranet2/Style%20Library/images/Contoso-Blue.png');
web.set_alternateCssUrl('/sites/intranet2/Style%20Library/CSS/Contoso.Intranet3.css');

web.update();
context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
```